# Can you unstick a sticky <thead>, before the end of the parent <table>?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table that has a sticky `<thead>` on mobile. However, when the table scrolls up the `<thead>` sticks until the very end.  This causes the last row to be covered by the header.

Is there a way to have the header unstick say 50px from the end of the table? This would allow the header to scroll up with the last row and not hide it.

If you have a CSS or jQuery solution, that would be ideal, but any method is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a margin to the table content to allow the header to flow into it's place, as if it wasn't sticky.

Comment: thank you for that suggestion.  Is there a way to add that margin after the header already hit the top?  I can't add more space between the table and the preceding element without it looking really goofy, due to the height of the header.

Comment: @Iisrael I found this which uses jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/noahkoch/wLcjh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a scrollspy library or use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to alter the stickiness of the heading depending on scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

I probably would use a separate div and leave the thead empty if you want custom control of the element on scroll. Wrap the div and table in a flex.container so they flow and relate to eachother.